# Accounting for "unknown" effects in regression using PCA

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, pca, predictor

I have gene expression data from cells grown in a dish over time - 5 time points, from 2 conditions: control and treatment.

Originally, I was interested in fitting a regression with treatment x time interaction. However, performing a PCA on the control data shows that the first PC explains 97% of the variance. I imagine that this mainly reflects changes in gene expression due to the density of the cells in the dish. As a result, I think that time is more a proxy for density in my data rather than anything else, and gene expression changes due to density are not my main interest. or this reason I'd like to account for that effect in my analysis.

There are two ways to do this which come to my mind but I could use some help:

1. Regress out the first PC (computed for the control data) from both the control and treatment data and treat all time points as replicates. I guess that would be `e_gi-<e_gi%*%pc1_i>*pc1_i` (where `e_gi` stands for expression of gene i and `pc1_i` is the *i*th element if the first PC vector), and `%*%` is dot product.
2. Add  the loadings of PC1 as a factor to the GLM which will therefore be: `e_gi ~ treatment + loading_PC1`

Any advice will be great.